# JQuery Ajax changes POST to GET

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, post, get

JQuery? keeps changing the form submission to a GET rather than a POST which keeps messing things up. Help! I've tried everything I know.

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('form#signup').on('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url : $(this).attr('action'),
                method : $(this).attr('method'),
                data : $(this).serialize()
            }).done(function(data) {
                alert("success");
            }).fail(function(data) {
                alert("fail");
            })
        });
    });
</script>
<form action="/signup" method="post" id="signup">
    <input type="text" value="test" name="registration_form[name]">
    <input type="text" value="test@test.com" name="registration_form[email]">
    <input type="text" value="9995551212" name="registration_form[phone]">
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="registration_form[submit]">
</form>
```

Comment: use `type:$(this).attr('method')` in ajax options,instead of `method : $(this).attr('method')`

Comment: Whats the difference between method and type in ajax options

Comment: Its the difference between JQuery v1.8 vs v1.9. 1.9 can use "method" or "type", 1.8 only uses type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('form#signup').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url : $(this).attr('action'),
            type: 'POST', // You can change this to GET if you want to submit via GET
            method : $(this).attr('method'),
            data : $(this).serialize()
        }).done(function(data) {
            alert("success");
        }).fail(function(data) {
            alert("fail");
        })
    });
});
</script>
```

You are missing the TYPE parameter for the Ajax request